# ConnectException: 'Connection refused'

Tags: aws, cassandra

My node worked normally, and I could use `nodetool status` normally, but when I changed `endpoint_snitch` to `Ec2Snitch` I started getting the error:

> nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused'.

Although it worked fine when `endpoint_snitch` was `SimpleSnitch`

The node private address is `10.0.5.247` and attached to security group that has `7199` open for inbound and outbound for the range that covers `10.0.5.247`

So, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ec2Snitch is specifically designed for Cassandra being installed in AWS EC2 instances. Please confirm if your installation is in AWS? In case you are, check whether listen address in cassandra.yaml is set to the private ip of the node (instead of localhost)

SimpleSnitch should work fine for Single datacenter. Its recommended to use GossipingPropertyFileSnitch for production.